is there python function to make non-unifrom warping
For example, perspective warping scales the width according to changes that occurred in the height of the image. I want a function that scales only the modified part (width or height) and I want it to be based on 4 points, so affine transformation is not appropriate for it.
original image:

perspective:

non-uniform:


GIMP has a  "cage transform" tool that does something along that. Unfortunatelly, I went to check, and there are no bindings  for the cage-transform tool using its procedure system (not even in the upcoming GIMP 3.0 ), so there is no way to use it from Python.
Sorry for that.

Cant you apply the transformatiom manually? In the example it looks you are squeezing the image in the y axis and the strength of the squeeze is determined by the X value. Such transformation should be very easy to implement.

@Elerium115 could you give an example about how to implementing it

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This forum is not a code writing service. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide some relevant code and we will help you debug it.

the "non-perspective"/"non-uniform" might be just a linear interpolation between the control points. this is also non-affine. -- you tagged opencv. do you need a solution using OpenCV? -- [mre] required.

You always have cv2.remap as a starting point, just gotta do the math ;) As Christoph mentions, that shouldn't be so hard, start with the case of just moving the top-right control point down, and go column-by-column. Once you figure that out, you can add the other axis. Get to that baseline, and you have some starting point to optimize it (and validate your optimizations as well).
